# Change version of CreateJS used by Animate CC

Tags: createjs, animate-cc

I am using **Adobe Animate CC 15.2.1.9**

I am creating projects using the **HTML5 Canvas** setup and when I check the generated files I can see that it is using `createjs-2015.11.26.min.js` from a CDN. This script tag is added at publish so can't be changed with a custom template.

Is there a way of changing the version of CreateJS that gets used without updating Animate CC itself (internal admin reasons mean this is not an option)?

Cheers

Comment: For the most part you an just point to a different version. We have gone to great lengths to make it all compatible, so pointing to a newer version should suffice. You can either use CDN links, or download a version at https://code.createjs.com

Comment: @Lanny - What is the simplest way to do that though? The links are added to the template by Animate at Publish. I don't really want to turn off overwriting or have to keep manually adding the link to the latest version. I wondered if there was a setting in Animate CC itself that allowed you to target certain versions of CreateJS when you publish

Comment: Some sort of option in Animate would be great, but unfortunately there is nothing like that. Typically I just turn off the overwrite, or make a duplicate to test with -- which should work unless there is something specific you need to change every time you publish.